# Render a RDL (Reporting Services) in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, service, ssrs-2008, reporting

Can I display report services file (RDL), direclty in a view with MVC (Razor)? Tried in various ways, but without success. Anyone have any useful tips about this?

Sorry for bad english.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot as the RDL file requires a viewer control which is a server side control to render the report. MVC Razor views do not support server side controls.

But.. you can add an `.aspx` page to your project and add a report viewer to that page. It won't work with the Razor `.vbhtml` or `.cshtml` files in MVC